# Not able to Extend RobotFramework SeleniumLibrary

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to extend the RobotFramework SeleniumLibrary:

```
class ReusableModule(SeleniumLibrary):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self, timeout=0.5, implicit_wait=15.0, **kwargs):
        logger.info("Reusable __init__")
        SeleniumLibrary.__init__(self, timeout=timeout, implicit_wait=implicit_wait, **kwargs)

    @keyword
    def open_browser(self, url, browser=env.capabilities.get("browserName"), alias=None, remote_url=env.host,
                     desired_capabilities=env.capabilities, ff_profile_dir=None):
        logger.info("Reusable open browser")
        return super(ReusableModule, self).open_browser(url=url, browser=browser, alias=alias, remote_url=remote_url,
                                                        desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
                                                        ff_profile_dir=ff_profile_dir)
```

I am getting the following error when I call this keyword in the RobotFramework Test:

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'open_browser'

Note: This worked in the past for Selenium2Library.

Comment: Yes, the new SeleniumLibrary was completely re-implemented with some sort of dynamic api, making it harder (or at least, undocumented) to extend.

Answer (score 0):

This has been added to the RFW SeleniumLibrary documentation 16.01.2018:
[Extending SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/extending/EXTENDING_SELENIUMLIBRARY.rst)

```
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword

class ExtendedSeleniumLibrary(SeleniumLibrary):
    @keyword
    def test(self):
        return "Extended SeleniumLibrary keyword"
```